# Is there a digitized version of the Tyndale Bible available?

Tags: bible, reference-request

Is there any websites that have a digitized version of William Tyndale's Bible online?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the absence of the Old Testament in the accepted website is that the Tyndale Bible did not include most of the Old Testament as he was only about half-way done translating it before he was executed.
This website includes the Old Testament books that he did complete: Genesis-Deuteronomy + Jonah, as well as the New Testament

http://wesley.nnu.edu/sermons-essays-books/william-tyndales-translation/